# Group data in pandas dataframe for every n years

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have data grouped by year in a dataframe. I have a column which has the year followed by data in various columns for each of these years. Is it possible to group the data for every five years?

```
Year Column 
1991   2
1992   3
1993   5
1994   7
1995   8
1996   9
1997   7
```

I need to group this data from 1991-1995 as one and from 1996-1997 as one and take the mean of the values. How do I perform this groupby operation?

Answer (score 4):

If the label doesn't matter, which can always be converted to more meaningful values like `1991-1995`, you can do:

```
df.Column.groupby(df.Year.sub(1991)//5).mean()

#Year
#0    5
#1    8
#Name: Column, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use `df.groupby(df.index//5).mean()`.

```
In [21]: df
Out[21]: 
   Year  Column
0  1991       2
1  1992       3
2  1993       5
3  1994       7
4  1995       8
5  1996       9
6  1997       7

In [22]: df.groupby(df.index//5).mean()
Out[22]: 
   Column
0       5
1       8
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the cut function here:

```
your_data_frame.groupby(pd.cut(your_data_frame["Year"], np.arange(0, 1991, 1995)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by [`numpy.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) with floor division and aggregate by [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) - `mean` and for ranges of years also `first` and `last`.

Remove MultiIndex in columns by `map` and [`insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) new column to first position with [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) and last remove columns by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
print (np.arange(len(df.index))//5)
[0 0 0 0 0 1 1]

df1 = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.index))//5).agg({'Column':'mean','Year':['first', 'last']})
df1.columns = df1.columns.map('_'.join)
df1.insert(0, 'Years', df1['Year_first'].astype(str) + '-' + df1['Year_last'].astype(str))
#instead insert if is not necessary first position of column
#df1['Years'] = df1['Year_first'].astype(str) + '-' + df1['Year_last'].astype(str)
df1.drop(['Year_first','Year_last'], axis=1, inplace=True)
print (df1)
       Years  Column_mean
0  1991-1995            5
1  1996-1997            8
```